# Parse an XML in standard C/C++ without additional libraries

Tags: c++, c, xml, parsing

I have an XML (assuming it is valid) and I must parse it and store it in a tree.

**What is the best approach to parse it, without using other libraries, just basic manipulation of strings?**

Keep in mind that I don't have to validate it, just parse and memorize it into a tree.

Comment: 1) write your own parser, using just basic manipulation of strings, 2) parse.

Comment: The best approach **is** to use a library. By far the best! :-)

Comment: The specs are here: [xml specs](http://www.w3.org/XML/Core/#Publications). Be aware that to comprehensively handle all the features of XML is not a trivial task.

Comment: You should ask about algorithms to parse. Please, add a algorithm tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic structure of XML is quite simple:

```
<tagname [attribute[="value"] ...]>content</tagname>
```

where the content may contain both normal text and more XML structures, or the special form

```
<tagname [attribute[="value"] ...]/>
```

which is equivalent to

```
<tagname [attribute[="value"] ...]></tagname>
```

that is,. empty content.

So if you don't need to interpret a DTD or do other fancy things, you can do the following:

1. Check that the first non-whitespace character is `<`. If not, you don't have XML and can just give an error and exit.
2. Now follows the tag name, until the first whitespace,  or the `/` or the `>` character. Store that.
3. If the next non-whitespace character is `/`, check that it is followed by `>`. If so, you've finished parsing and can return your result. Otherwise, you've got malformed XML, and can exit with an error.
4. If the character is `>`, then you've found the end of the begin tag. Now follows the content. Continue at step 6.
5. Otherwise what follows is an argument. Parse that, store the result, and continue at step 3.
6. Read the content until you find a `<` character.
7. If that character is followed by `/`, it's the end tag. Check that it is followed by the tag name and `>`, and if yes, return the result. Otherwise, throw an error.
8. If you get here, you've found the beginning of a nested XML. Parse that with this algorithm, and then continue at 6.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me a lot to understand the general process of parsing the xml:)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, I forgot comments. Processing instructions and marked sections belong to the "other fancy things" I mentioned in the beginning. Another thing I omitted, though, is named entities; however I believe those can be handled by post-processing the content.

Comment: @celtschk: But you're confusing producer and consumer. Validating against a DTD is "fancy stuff" on part of the consumer, and that's OK to skip. But PIs can come from *any* producer. As always, you can provide as little as you like, but you have to accept as much as is allowed by the standard.

Comment: (Also, given that there's at least one PI that is *very* ubiquitous, your "parser" would probably fail immediately on most real-world XML.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Anyway, this is a homework question. I'm not supposed to give a complete solution anyway.

Comment: Also `="value"` are not optional in XML, contrary to what this answer suggests.

Answer (score 6):

Reading XML looks simple but doing it correctly involves a few complexities you don't really want to deal with. Indeed, writing a simple XML parser effectively amounts to creating yet another XML library. I have done it and an incomplete version of this is sitting somewhere on my disk. Even if you don't need to validate your XML structure:

- whether you validate or not, you need to deal with entity references like `&lt;` and the variety of character entity references like `&#65;` and `&#xa;`
- the plain body of an XML document is relatively simple but the header a major pain to deal with in particular the DTD: there are two versions thereof which are slightly different and you probably need to process the inline DTD
- even the body isn't entirely trivial because of these annoying character data segments
- even without validation you may need to support external entity references
- the characters to be accepted and/or rejected for various parts of XML are also somewhat interesting
- note that XML is defined in terms of Unicode and proper handling of this isn't entirely trivial either: just using `char` or `wchar_t` just doesn't cut it.

The first version I implemented was a nice little iterator intended to pop out all the elements encountered. This allowed for the nice feature of easily stopping and continuing the parsing at the choice of the iterator user. Unfortunately, I didn't get it to fly when trying to copy with the various entity references. It would parse simple XML files nice and fast but some quirks in the specification I just didn't get right.

What worked best for me was creating a simple recursive decent parser combined with a suitable stack of buffers to somewhat transparently deal with entity references. However, to finish this completely I still need to deal with some encoding issues and in the end I just had higher priority projects to work on (in my spare time, that is).

In summary: it can be done, obviously, as others did. It is probably a somewhat pointless exercise unless you have a really bright idea which makes your implementation uniquely better suited than the alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I think i'm going for the iterator, i don't want to get somewhat complicated with recursivity, buffers and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The best and *only* approach is to re-implement such a library *from scratch* without using any other libraries...

You're welcome to use existing libraries like [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/), for example. It's installation is as simple as adding the files to your project and start using it. It's lightweight compared to other validating parsers, such as Xerces.

Comment: Tnx for answers. To use an existing library is not an option. It's just a homework for a course, i don't have to handle all XML features, just to parse it trivially. My question was what's the best method to parse it? I have a bit of experience in c++, but not in working with strings.

Comment: @Andrei: then you had to write so in the OP.